# IF statement inside of a function call? Code help

Tags: c++

I was browsing a library for steppers motors when I ran across this line of foreign-looking code:

```
digitalWrite(enable_pin, (enable_active_state == HIGH) ? LOW : HIGH);
```

Is this some kind of shortcut to tossing an if statement into a function call? I've never seen this before. What exactly does it do, and what is this particular arrangement of code called?

Thanks!

Comment: Google something like "C++ ternary operator". There are many good explanations for that operator online

Comment: It could probably have been shortened to this instead:
digitalWrite(enable_pin, ! enable_active_state ) ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at this as an "if expression", the correct term is "conditional operator" (C++ standard chapter 8.16). Many know it as "ternary operator" because it has three operands. You might already know the "unary operator" with one operand like the negation sign `-x`, or the "binary operator" with two operands like the addition `a + b`.

This expression consists of:

- the first operand
- the operator `?`
- the second operand
- the operator `:`
- the third operand

The first operator is evaluated and converted (if necessary) into a boolean.

If the result is `true`, the second operand is evaluated and gives the value of the expression.

If the result is `false`, the third operand is evaluated and gives the value of the expression.

Only one of the second and third operands is evaluated. This is important, if you use operands with side effects, like function calls can have.

This operator is often frowned upon. If used excessively, the source becomes easily unreadable. Many professional code style guide prohibit its use for this reason.

In your case it could have been written more clearly as

```cpp
if (enable_active_state == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(enable_pin, LOW);
} else {
    digitalWrite(enable_pin, HIGH);
}
```

It outputs the inverted value of the variable `enable_active_state` at the pin `enable_pin`.

Experienced Arduino users know that `HIGH` and `LOW` are represented in a way that are compatible with boolean values. Boolean inversions can be simpler expressed with the logical negation operator:

```cpp
digitalWrite(enable_pin, !enable_active_state);
```

Anyway, the current compilers are commonly smart enough to generate the same machine code for each of the variants. Therefore, please write your source in the best way to express your intention. Anything else is "premature optimization", which is a bad thing. But this is a completely other topic.